# Using Dense Training Data for Prediction on Sparse Testing Data for SVD yields poor performance

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, svd, collaborative-filtering

I am implementing collaborative filtering(like netflix) using SVD and I am encountering an issue where my training data is very dense relative to the testing set. The algorithm returns no recommendations for most of my testing data. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

To make this more concrete the training data has long documents(wikipedia) but the testing data only has one or two non-zero entries (short phrases written by users).

Comment: Can you give more details about your implementation? Collaborative filtering and SVD normally have user-item-rating tuples as input, and output either predicted ratings for a user-item pair or a set of items as top-N recommendations. How are you using documents instead of (or feeding into) traditional collaborative filtering?